# Paging controls not showing in Mage2 listing page (ui_component)

Tags: admin, magento-2.1, uicomponent, pagination

Here's the relevant portion of the XML to create a listing page. For some reason the paging component won't show. I've been looking over this for hours, any idea where I need to look next to enable pagination?

```
<listingToolbar name="fulfillment_code_grid_top">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
        </item>
    </argument>

    <bookmark name="bookmarks">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/bookmarks/bookmarks</item>
                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">fulfillment_code_grid</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </bookmark>

    <paging name="fulfillment_code_grid_paging">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">fulfillment_code_grid.fulfillment_code_grid.fulfillment_code_grid_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                </item>
                <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">fulfillment_code_grid.fulfillment_code_grid.fulfillment_columns.ids</item>
                <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="20" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="value" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">20</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="30" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="value" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">30</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="50" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="value" xsi:type="number">50</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">50</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="100" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="value" xsi:type="number">100</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">100</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="200" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="value" xsi:type="number">200</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">200</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </paging>
</listingToolbar>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out, by installing a [sample plugin](https://www.ashsmith.io/magento2/module-from-scratch-introduction/) and hacking on its `<paging>` tag.

I discovered it can be as simple as `<paging name="listing_paging">`, however the catch seems to be the `name="listing_paging"` part. Originally had `name="fulfillment_code_grid_paging"`; changing it brought the control onto the page.